AdminLte SCSS file not working properly after migration to Angular 18
I migrated an old company project from Angular 7 to Angular 18, mostly everything works again now, but for some reason, the login screen is still broken. In the original Angular 7 version, the login box is centered on the screen, but after migrating, it broke and now it's all the way to the left of the website.
What it should look like:
Ideal
What is looks like now:
Current
After inspecting the elements, I found that there was a difference between the good (older) version of the website and the new one I'm working on, mainly that the class "login-box" is missing a margin : 7% auto in the new version. After manually adding it into the website through the inspector, it works as usual.
Typed in css manually
The scss is from root.scss so I looked at the files and found this scss file comes from the AdminLte extension, but when I search through the project files, the specified file doesn't actually have the scss declarations.
Can't find it in project files
I don't know much about how to use bootstrap, and was hoping you guys could help me on this

in angular.json or main scss file must be import adminlte scss file, check it

@НикитаСереда I checked and it was there. I ended up pasting the manual change to the css into the referenced css file and it works now, but a lot of other ui elements are still broken
